# Query for getting the result from multiple core in solr with same schema

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, solr, nopcommerce

I have two core in one solr application one is for quering on the "Main Core" and another one is for indexing the data "Index Core".Schema file is same in both core.

After indexing the data in "Index Core", I want to query on the "Main Core" to get the result.

How can I query for that in solrnet?

Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

It isn't 100% clear from your question, however SolrNet is capable of maintaining multiple cores/connections at a time. Simple call Startup.Init on multiple cores with the associated different url pattern. The schema can be the same, just use the same type.

```
        var solrConnectionProducts = new SolrConnection(SolrServerUrl + "/products");
        Startup.Init<SolrProductDocument>(solrConnectionProducts);

        var solrConnectionProducts2 = new SolrConnection(SolrServerUrl + "/products2");
        Startup.Init<SolrProductDocument>(solrConnectionProducts2);
```

The only thing I am confused by is your statement of using two different cores for querying and indexing. This is strange to me as the typical use case is to index your data and then query it both on the same core if the schema and data is the same.